# Turn Chunk of Files into Pages in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, file, spring-mvc

I have a code where i read a large file in chunks and transform it into JSON to send it to a Spring MVC controller, my method looks something like this, i pass where i want to start in the offset and the chunkSize in the noBytes, the result is passed to be transformed into JSON and  sent to my controller

```
  public String readByteBlock(File file, int offset, int noBytes) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] result = new byte[noBytes];
    in.skip(offset);
    in.read(result, 0, noBytes);
    return FileSaver.byteArrayToString(result, noBytes);
}
```

I am having problem to make the next and previous pagination work in my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/page/{id}")
@ResponseBody   
    File file = new File("C:/teste.txt");
    FileSaver fs = new FileSaver();
    int byteblock = 100;        
    int offset = 0;
    if(id.equals("next")){      
        offset = (int) req.getSession().getAttribute("prevEndPos"); 
        String s = fs.readByteBlock(file, offset, byteblock);       
        req.getSession().setAttribute("prevStartPos", offset);     
        req.getSession().setAttribute("prevEndPos", (offset + byteblock) );       
        return s;
    }
    if(id.equals("prev")){
        offset = (int) req.getSession().getAttribute("prevStartPos") - byteblock ; 
        if(offset < 0 ){
            String s = fs.readByteBlock(file, 0, byteblock);
              return s;
        }
        String s = fs.readByteBlock(file, offset, byteblock);         
        req.getSession().setAttribute("prevStartPos", (offset - byteblock) );      
        return s;
    }
    String s = fs.readByteBlock(file, 0, byteblock);
    req.getSession().setAttribute("prevStartPos", offset);
    req.getSession().setAttribute("prevEndPos", (offset + byteblock));
    return s;
```

So each chunk of the file will be put into an html table in my application,i  saved the current block startByte and endByte into my session but when the user press the previous button on my page how do i know where the previous block started and ended? since the session will hold the current page and not the previous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a little general about pagination.
Simple pagination only has two properties:

1. A page size
2. A page number

The back-end will sends back the data and the following metadata:

1. Total number of pages
2. The current page number
3. The current page size

The client is then responsible for asking for the chunk of data it wants, by sending the page number and page size, the backend will then calculate the offset and end. The only thing to be aware of is that if the user increases the page size, then the total number of pages (that the client received in the previous call) is no longer valid, but in those case the server just returns no data, and new metadata.
This approach is used by many frameworks, like Spring Data on the backend, and EXT JS for front-end.

Since you are using Spring, you should just create a DTO class that holds both the data and meta data:

```
Class PageResult {
    String data;
    int totalPageCount;
    int currentPage;
    int pageSize;       
}
```

In you are using String for the transporting data be aware that you may have to call JSON.parse() on the front-end, and your JSON will be string escaped which looks silly; if you are reading you data using Jacksons ObjectMapper I would recommend using a ObjectMapper.readTree() which returns a JsonNode, and put that into your DTO class.

On the front-end you can do a dropdown with suggested page sizes, and an input box for the page number. If you want next and previous, just send a request with current page +/- 1 and the page size, then the backend will calculate start, end and total pages.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding two int attributes to your session, why not add two arrays of ints, containing the appropriate values? And also add a 'page' attribute, so you can do something like

```
if(id.equals("prev") {
    List<Integer> offsetStarts = req.getSession.getAttribute("offsetStarts);
    List<Integer> offsetEnds = req.getSession.getAttribute("offsetEnds);
    int lastPage = req.getSession.getAttribute("page");
    int desiredPage = lastPage -1;
    int offsetStart = offsetStarts.get(desiredPage);
    int offsetEnd = offsetEnd.get(desiredPage);
    // get the chunk as desired, and return it
    req.getSession().setAttribute("page", desiredPage);
}
// if it's a new chunk, append offsets to the arrays
```